# ¿ Como actualizar después de un registro un campo null?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

buen día a todos, agradezco a quienes se toman la molestia de leer mi inquietud

Acudo a ustedes después de probar ya varias cosas, Tengo una tabla en la cual cuando se hace un registro un campo queda vacío, es decir null(el campo lo dejo null de aposta), este campo es de tipo date: `$table->date('rdate');`

Mi problema es el siguiente, cuando trato de actualizar el campo vacío es decir 'rdate', no pasa nada, sigue en null, el código que tengo es este:

```
public function RegisterWorkPermit($id)
{
    $registerWorkPermit = WorkPermit::findOrFail($id);

    $registerWorkPermit -> update
    ([
        'rdate'=>Carbon::now(),
    ]);
    return back()->with('notification','Aceptado correctamente');
}
```

tengo la sospecha que si no hubo un registro previo este no se actualizara, ya que probé con campos no null, les agardeceria que me aconsejaran, ya que tengo mas campos null que me gustaría actualizar mas adelante

[image: Aquí mi tabla]

Por cierto como puedo formatear los campos pexit y preturn (son tipo time) para que en la vista luzcan así:  5:27 pm

Gracias :D

Comment: Creería que `update` no funciona así. Puedes hacer `WorkPermit::where('id', $id)-> update([ 'rdate'=>Carbon::now(),  ]);` o usar `findOrFail` y luego `save()`. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#updates

Comment: Estoy casi seguro de que te falta agregar ese campo `rdate` a tu modelo. Qué campos tienes en tu modelo llamado WorkPermit?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ update sí funciona así

Comment: @L.Flor Ah, sí, perdón, sí funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siguiendo  la documentación de laravel [update con eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#updates) la manera de actualizar un modelo mediante eloquent es llamando al método save() ejemplo:

```
$flight = App\Flight::find(1);

$flight->name = 'New Flight Name';

$flight->save();
```

En tu caso lo haces mediante el método update y por el por código muestras no aparenta ningún error solo queda revisar si en le modelo dentro del array de fillable tienes el campo que quires actualizar

```
protected $fillable = ['rdate'];
```

Comment: Ese era el error faltaba 'rdate' en el modelo, gracias